# typescript type is not assignable to type `symbol` error

Tags: typescript

```js
export type anchorPositionType = "middle" | "left" | "right" | "top" | "bottom" | customAnchorType;
export type customAnchorType = { rightness?: number; bottomness?: number };

const getAnchorOffset = (width:number, height:number): { [key in anchorPositionType]: customAnchorType } => // here 'anchorPositionType' getting the error Type 'customAnchorType' is not assignable to type 'symbol' and i don't understand why?
 {
   return {
     middle: { rightness: width * 0.5, bottomness: height * 0.5 },
     left: { rightness: 0, bottomness: height * 0.5 },
     right: { rightness: width, bottomness: height * 0.5 },
     top: { rightness: width * 0.5, bottomness: 0 },
     bottom: { rightness: width, bottomness: height * 0.5 }
   };
};
```

i cant figure out what is the problem. why `anchorPositionType` at the function signature getting the error `Type 'customAnchorType' is not assignable to type 'symbol'`?

Comment: Symbols are a primitive unique value and can be used as keys in an object.

Comment: you mean that `customAnchorType` must be a string so he could be used as a key in object?

Comment: Could you explain what are you trying to do and why `| customAnchorType` is part of `anchorPositionType` (that's what causing the problem)

Comment: I writing arrows (or lines)lib in react. I want the user to able you define anchor by using a string of some trivial anchor or define one by himself.

Comment: i've solved my problem. (just excluded customAnchorType from anchorPositionType).
i will not delete this question because maybe other users will encounter the same error.

Comment: Yeah :) that's what I've told you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in my case the compiler complained that `customAnchorType` is not a union type so the `in` operator can't be used on him.

```js
type anchorPositionType = 'middle' | 'left' | 'right' | 'top' | 'bottom' | customAnchorType;
type customAnchorType = { rightness?: number; bottomness?: number };
type test = { [key in anchorPositionType]: customAnchorType };
                      ^
    Type 'customAnchorType' is not assignable to type 'symbol'. 
    
    ('customAnchorType' is an object)
```

if we will remove `customAnchorType` from `anchorPositionType`:

```js
type anchorPositionType = 'middle' | 'left' | 'right' | 'top' | 'bottom'
```

the error would disapear because now `anchorPositionType` is one of `middle' | 'left' | 'right' | 'top' | 'bottom`